# React Native bottom modal with horizontal scroll

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to get a modal working to look like the picture below. I've tried various modal and actionsheet solutions but can't quite get it right. Does anyone know if a solution exists that can provide a similar result? Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9HBf.png)

I have been using an action sheet from a library (pic below) but it cannot be customized to scroll horizontally and use custom buttons. I also have not yet attempted in creating my own, I first wanted to know if anyone knows of a component which will yield the same result.

Regular action sheet on iOS
[image]

Comment: You have to include some code so people can see what you have so far to help you.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find a solution to how to complete the ticket quantity modal?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple working example as per your requirement. I am using [react-native-modal](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal) for Modal component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView
  } from 'react-native'
import Modal from 'react-native-modal'

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      visible: false
    }
  }

  showModal = () => this.setState({visible: true})

  hideModal = () => this.setState({visible: false})

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <TouchableOpacity 
        onPress={this.showModal}
        style={{alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 50, backgroundColor: 'grey'}}
        >
          <Text>Touch Me</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Modal
          style={styles.modal}
          isVisible={this.state.visible}
          onBackdropPress={this.hideModal}
          >
          <ScrollView 
          horizontal={true}
          >
             {/* place your buttons here */}
            <Text>  Very Very Long String  </Text>
          </ScrollView>
          </Modal>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  modal: {
    margin: 0, 
    backgroundColor: 'white', 
    height: 100, 
    flex:0 , 
    bottom: 0, 
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%'
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks @rahul. This does exactly what I want it to.